# Unexpected end of input response from wp_handle_upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The file uploads through ajax no problem, but when a json encoded array is returned to ajax I get this error when trying to parse it:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Client Side Script

```
jQuery(".target-input").change(function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.files[0]);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "../wp-content/plugins/site_bannermanager/site_ajax_server_add.php",
    file: formData
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
  });
});
```

site_ajax_server_add.php

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $data) {
  exit(json_encode(wp_handle_upload($data)));
}
```

Comment: Ehh you exit in the first foreach and expect all the data to appear? You need to construct an array of elements and then echo them, not kill the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".target-input").change(function () {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.files[0]);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "../wp-content/plugins/site_bannermanager/site_ajax_server_add.php",
    file: formData,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(response));
    }
  });
});
```

Should do the trick. Looks like your forgot some of your closing brackets. I also made the success function a bit better (but you can change it back if you want, I just think it makes it more readable.